# Access Django DB from Task

Tags: python, database, django

Is it possible to update the DB from a Django App, from an Other python Script. The plan is to fetch Sensor Data over an Tcp/ip Connection, Write it to the DB and the Django app can Display the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, all you have to do is to import the project settings.

```
import os
sys.path.append('relative/path/to/settings/file')
from django.conf import settings 
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "settings"
```

After that you just import all the models you want to work with, also do the append the directory to them (models.py).

Comment: Yes it does. I use this method when running py files to perform some tasks for my django project.

Comment: I will give it a try! Thanks! Any other ideas how One can do it / perhaps with other Frameworks?